# How to detect 'select' option when multiple attributes have same id

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

```
<input id="Proc#fr#2-1-111" type="text" data-ctrl="JSCtrl" name="fr" style="display: none; background-color: rgb(224, 224, 224); width: 80px;" disabled=""/>
<select id="Proc#fr#2-1-111" data-ctrl="JSCtrl" name="fr" optionsdict="3,25 cm,4,29.97 cm,5,30 cm" style="border: 1px solid rgb(127, 157, 185); width: 80px;">
<select id="Proc#fr#2-1-111" data-ctrl="JSCtrl" name="fr" optionsdict="3,25 cm,4,29.97 cm,5,30 cm,6,50 cm,7,59.94 cm,8,60 cm" style="border: 1px solid rgb(127, 157, 185); display: none; width: 80px;" disabled="">
```

In the above code, id is same for input, select. I need to choose a value in select. Is it possible via selenium webdriver using python?

Comment: The "correct" solution would be to eliminate the duplicate IDs.

Comment: html code cant be changed. I need to find select option with existing html code

Comment: That code is not well formed html. `Id` cannot be duplicate. Instead of fixing the symptom you should fix the source.

Comment: Will you be knowing the values of optionsdict for every select in advance? If yes, then there might be a solution. Please let me know.

Comment: You can use xpath. Two ways to do this. The first will involve drilling down from the parent of the input tag. The second you can do this //input[@id='Proc#fr#2-1-111' and @type='text']

Comment: Hey Vinay, I am interested in second tag , the only difference is that style does not have display:none . Can anyone let me know how to find element by means id combined with style tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this HTML is not well formed. Duplicate IDs should be avoided. If you don't have access to modify the source code, talk to your manager please. Selenium developers should be able to change source whenever needed.

For the question about "how to find element by means id combined with style tag", here is how you can achieve it.

Use CSS Selector

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select[id='Proc#fr#2-1-111']:not([style*='display: none'])")
```

Use XPath

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//select[@id='Proc#fr#2-1-111' and not(contains(@style, 'display: none'))]")
```

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I will try solutions given by you. As per HTML code it is legacy code so cant be changed by me but I will bring to my manager's notice